# AngularJS: How to hide an element when it's too big?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/roJC9X

See the link above. I want to hide the textarea when the width of the text area is over 400px. How can this be done?

Comment: you mean, you want to hide the text area when the browser is wider then 400px?

Comment: no I want to hide the textarea when it is itself > 400px

Comment: so you need to listen for the resize event of the textarea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Angular and you're dealing with view related code, you'd want to define a `directive`.

The code below is an example of what this directive would look like (written in CoffeeScript):

```
angular.module('yourAppName').directive('hideOnExceed', ->
  return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: (scope, element, attr) ->
      element.bind 'resize', ->
        if element.width() > 400
          element.hide()
        else
          element.show()
  }
)
```

Then simply define `hideOnExceed` as an attribute to the textarea tag:

`<textarea ng-show="withinSize()" hideOnExceed>{{size}}</textarea>`