# How to determine the height of a InputTextarea of primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using a InputTextarea with autoresize = "false" from primefaces wanted to see how you could get your height and width using JQuery, this I'm already handling some stuff in a function JQuery but I need to know the height and width of my inputTextarea, I see its height and width depending on when this resizing.

Comment: Hi Adan, doesn't JQuerys `$(document.getElementById(<yourInputTextAreasId)).height()` give the height of an textarea?

Comment: But if I need this update depending on when this resizing the InputTextarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the post [Resize event for textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570443/1269441) describes how to get notified when a resize of a textarea takes place. As function being called, just use something like

```
$(document.getElementById(<yourInputTextAreasId)).height()
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: thanks for your help, I was able to obtain the data which required