# Textarea: Apply a style on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a textarea on my page, with `resize:both;`

I want to be able to apply a style to that textarea only when the user resizes it. Preferably I would like to be able to do this with CSS, but I dont think there is a pseudo-selector or method that would work with just pure CSS. Am I wrong?

Failing this, is there an event I can make use of in jQuery?

And what would be the best way of reseting the textarea to its original size? Would this be with jQuery again?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I've read it to fast. Deleted my comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea

Comment: All the answers are going wrong, she wants to apply style only when resize event is carried on

Comment: @Mr.Alien : Arun's link is right direction!! :)

Comment: what about my answer? am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @C-link : haha..no fella...u r also on right track!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor that's why I mentioned answers, and great, even you posted one..

Comment: @Mr.Alien : i had doubt on my answer...-1 nailed the doubt, so deleted it...answering back after a gap can be difficult!! :)

Comment: Did you guys check my answer. Do you want me to update anything there.

Comment: @ScriptShiva I am just weighing up the relative merits of using your jQueryUI solution and using A. Wolff's version without an additional library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any other library, creating own resize event for textarea could be done like this:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUveZ/)

```
$('textarea').on({
    mousedown: function(){
        $(this).data('size', $(this).width + '*' + $(this).height());
    },
    mouseup: function(){
        if($(this).data('size') !=  $(this).width + '*' + $(this).height())
            $(this).triggerHandler('resize');
    },
    resize: function(){
        console.log('textarea resized!');
    }
});
```

Comment: although the jQueryUI resizable method is an excellent solution to this problem, I ended up using an adaptation of this code, so I'm going to mark you as correct.

Comment: @Jimmery I accept it. This is a nice solution. Unless you already use JqueryUI, i hope it would be a pain to load whole library for a single functionality. Anyway in future if you use it my answer might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first make the textarea resizable before issuing the resize event. You can do that by using [jQuery UI resizable()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) and inside it you can call the resize event.

**CSS**

```
.resizing {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #4cf;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("textarea").resizable({ // Making it resizables triggers resize associated events
    resize: function() {
        $(this).addClass('resizing'); // Add style while resizing
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('resizing'); // Remove style after resize finishes
    }
});
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dqWD9/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
$("#mytextarea").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        $(this).css("resize","both");
    }
});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/gR9UV/**](http://jsfiddle.net/gR9UV/)

Comment: You forgot to say that you need jQuery UI to get this to work.