# Track user-resizing of multiline textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have build a website with a Multiview and two Views.

A "live"-View and a "edit"-View.

In the editview the user should be able to resize one or more Multiline Textboxes.

Everything works fine except for how do i track the resizing?
I dont know how to "save" the width and height of the Textbox.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea

Comment: Thanks - currently looking into the posts.