# Is there a way to use javascript to find the width of a textarea element, even when the corner is pulled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `textarea` element, and I am trying to find the height of it.  Right now, I am using `document.getElementById('area').offsetHeight`.  This does give me the height, however, I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically update this if I enlarge the `textarea`.  Right now, even if I pull on the corner and make the `textarea` taller, the javascript returns the same result.  Is there a way to update the height when I pull the corner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize event for textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea)

Comment: @WesFoster I do not want to use jQuery

Comment: The same logic would apply to pure JavaScript. Bind a mouse event to the textarea, then re-check its dimensions.

Comment: @WesFoster Which event to bind? `textarea` doesn't fire native `resize` ...

Comment: @Teemu `onmouseup`

Comment: @WesFoster If OP doesn't care the event firing on every mouseup anywhere on the textarea, then that'll do the trick.

Comment: @WesFoster is there a way to recheck the height and save that as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript onmouseup event. Using the console.log you can see that the value changes.

```js
function mouseUp() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('area').offsetHeight);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" onmouseup="mouseUp()"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the new height as a variable instead of logging it?

Comment: @Matt Its just javascript, you'd use it the same as you would anywhere else, i.e.

var newHeight;
newHeight = document.getElementById('area').offsetHeight;