# Textarea detect user input and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea and I need to record when a user edits the text and also this text area is resizable. I would like to detect when the text area gets resized. Could you let me know the functions that I could use.

Thanks

Comment: Well I am sure you know what the first event is to detect if the user changed the text... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: Look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea

Comment: I am actually saving this data from a text area to a session variable which I can use for later. I need to store values when the  textarea is getting resized without any delay as there is a chance that users can just go to another page. it is critical for my application to record these changes.  This should work in almost all the browsers.

Comment: mutation observer doesn't work in safari.