# Angular-resize-event not working for textarea

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to check the width and height of `<textarea>` as I resize it in real time not after I release the click so I tried to use Angular-resize-event. But its not working out it seems like this is only applicable to `<div>` not `<textarea>`. I also tried to wrap`<textarea>` in`<div>` but this does not work only the Height parameter changes but the width remains same . Why is it so ? Is there another way to do this ?
her is my code  :

HTML

```
     <div (resized)='onResize($event)'><textarea #resizable></textarea>      
     </div>
<div><span> HEIGHT : {{height}} </span> WIDTH : {{width}} </div>
```

Component.ts

```
  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizedEvent } from 'angular-resize-event';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('resizable') box: ElementRef ;



  onResize(event:ResizedEvent) {
    this.height =  event.newHeight;

    this.width = event.newWidth;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is not detecting a change in width on your parent `<div>`, is because, the parent `<div>`'s width seems to be set as 100% by default. You will need to use the css property `display`, and set the value as `inline-block`.

```
<div (resized)="onResize($event)" style="display:inline-block">
  <textarea #resizable></textarea>      
</div>
```

With that, the `resized` event should be able to capture changes in both width and height!

I have forked and re-created the demo for you over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybykqx?file=src/app/app.component.html). Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: But why can't I use it directly in  `<textarea>` ?

Comment: @johnsmith Hmm.. I have no idea why. It seems like that library only works on `<div>` element?

Comment: Ok , so is there a workaround that if I want to do it for `<textarea>` ? I was thinking of implementing a function which after a few milliseconds look for change in width and height of `<textarea>` but I dont know how to implement it .

Comment: Hmm.. In that case, you might want to create your own directive, and use `HostListener`. You might find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158863/html-textarea-resize-event-with-angular