# How to get postition highlighted text in textarea (coords) angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to get something like this, in textarea. I cant change textarea to contentaditable div. How do I get the position of the selected text? I need this to show this pop-up from above
[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily convert this into angular code.
This is the basics of what you need to do, its not thoroughly tested but it bare minimum works.

[image: Working example]

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('text')
const result = document.getElementById('selected')
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')

const cols = document.getElementById('text').cols;
const width = document.getElementById('text').clientWidth;
const height = window.getComputedStyle(textarea).lineHeight;


textarea.onclick = function getSelection() {
  const pos = {
    top: textarea.offsetTop,
    left: textarea.offsetLeft,
  };
  result.textContent = `${textarea.selectionStart}, ${textarea.selectionEnd}`;
  let selection
  if (textarea.selectionStart) {
    selection = textarea.selectionStart;
  } else if (document.selection) {
    textarea.focus();
    const r = document.selection.createRange();
    if (r == null) {
      selection = 0;
    }
    let re = textarea.createTextRange();
    let rc = re.duplicate();
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
    selection = rc.text.length;
  } else {
    selection = 0
  }
  const row = Math.floor((selection - 1) / cols);
  const col = (selection - (row * cols));
  const x = Math.floor((col * (width / cols)));
  const y = (parseInt(height) * row);
  tooltip.innerHTML = "<b>row: " + row + "<br>columns" + col + "<br>width: " + width + "</b>";
  tooltip.style.top = `${pos.top+y}px`;
  tooltip.style.left = `${pos.left+x+10}px`;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 12px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">Lopsum</textarea>
<span id="tooltip"></span>
<span id="selected"></span>
```

Comment: How can knowing the index help me in displaying a popup? I would like to know the height and width at which the selection is located

Comment: width: 151 every time

Comment: Thats the width of the text area, its static. Please check code first.

Comment: but i need postition of selected text in px

Comment: The x, y positioning should be equal to `tooltip.style.left, tooltip.style.top`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I imagine is create a duplicate of the text area (very similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899473/highlight-specific-words-in-textarea-angular-8), (the Owen Kelvin's response) about highligth words in a text area

As we only need the position, we can split the "texarea" and the "background". Futhermore, using the Yurzui response in this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158863/html-textarea-resize-event-with-angular) we can control when resize the textarea

We can imagine an .html like

```
<div class="container">
    <div
      #backdrop
      class="backdrop"
      [style.width.px]="textWidth"
      [style.height.px]="textHeight"
    >
      <div
        class="highlights"
        [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(highlightedText)"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea
    #textarea
    spellcheck="false"
    (resize)="rect = null;"
    (select)="applyHighlights(textarea.value)"
    (mousedown)="mouseDown()"
    (blur)="rect = null"
    [ngModel]="textValue"
    (ngModelChange)="textValue = $event; applyHighlights(textarea.value)"
    (scroll)="handleScroll(); applyHighlights(textarea.value)"
  ></textarea>

<div
  class="tooltip"
  *ngIf="rect"
  [style.top.px]="rect.y"
  [style.left.px]="rect.x"
></div>
```

See that the "text" is hidden because we has a div container like

```
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
```

And we make that the dimensions of "text" are condition by the two variables           "textWidth" and "textHeight"

The code is

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resize();
  }

  resize() {
    const event = {
      width: this.$textarea.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width,
      height: this.$textarea.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    };
    this.textWidth = event.width;
    this.textHeight = event.height;
  }
  mouseDown() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const start = this.$textarea.nativeElement.selectionStart;
      const end = this.$textarea.nativeElement.selectionEnd;
      if (start == end) this.rect = null;
    });
  }
  applyHighlights(text: string) {
    if (text) {
      let start = this.$textarea.nativeElement.selectionStart;
      let end = this.$textarea.nativeElement.selectionEnd;
      if (start == end) this.highlightedText = text;
      else {
        const selected = text.substr(start, end - start);
        this.toolTipText=this.getTooltipText(selected)
        this.highlightedText =
          text.substr(0, start) +
          "<span id='mark'>" +
          selected +
          '</span>' +
          text.substr(end);
        this.resize();
        setTimeout(() => {
          const recArea = this.$textarea.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
          const recText = this.$backdrop.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

          const rect = document.getElementById('mark').getBoundingClientRect();
          rect.y += window.scrollY;
          rect.x+=rect.width/2
          this.rect = rect.y - window.scrollY < recArea.y ? null : rect;
        });
      }
    }

  }
  handleScroll() {
    var scrollTop = this.$textarea.nativeElement.scrollTop;
    this.$backdrop.nativeElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;

    var scrollLeft = this.$textarea.nativeElement.scrollLeft;
    this.$backdrop.nativeElement.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
  }
```

And in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-textarea-highlight-k8azjp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftextarea-highlight%2Ftextarea-highlight.component.ts) I put in a custom form component (the reason is that Owen make this work for me