# Detect <textarea> resize event in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an auto-sizing `<textarea>` that's working great.  I want to allow the user to manually resize it with the handlebar, at which point, auto-sizing becomes disabled.  How do I capture the `onresize` event?  According to @types/react, `onResize` isn't available.

Here's what I have so far.

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

export default class MyInput extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      autosize: true,
      value: ''
    };
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const input = event.target;
    this.setState({ value: input.value });
    if (this.state.autosize) {
      const offset = input.offsetHeight - input.clientHeight;
      input.style.height = 'auto';
      input.style.height = input.scrollHeight + offset + 'px';
    }
  }

  onResize() {
    this.setState({ autosize: false });
  }

  render() {
    return <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5570390/1552587) to see a couple of example of how you could monitor the manual resize of the element.

Comment: Ah, I looked at that question, but it uses JQuery, so I didn't scan all the answers.  I'll take a look.

Comment: There are some examples that use vanilla JavaScript, the problem is not with React, the problem is that there isn't any `onresize` event triggered when the `<textarea>` is resized. Most of the solutions use mouse events and check the elements size before and after.

Comment: Looks like there's a `ResizeObserver` class that's implemented in Firefox and Chrome.  I'll use that.

Comment: [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) is not supported in Safari, there are a lot of Safari users out there.

Comment: It's a best-effort sort of thing.  A nice-to-have.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be the experimental (as of 11/2019) [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) class.  It's currently implemented in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but not in Edge or Safari.

```js
export default class MyInput extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      autosize: true,
      canResize: true,
      value: ''
    };

    this.inputRef = react.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.ResizeObserver) {
      const input = this.inputRef.current,
        observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
          this.setState({ autosize: false });
          observer.disconnect();
        });

      observer.observe(input);
    } else {
      this.setState({ canResize: false });
    }
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return <textarea {...} ref={this.inputRef} 
             style={{ resize: this.state.canResize ? 'vertical' : 'none' }} />
  }
}
```