# HTML textarea resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, dom-events

I'm looking for a way to run some JS when a textarea gets resized.

After an hour of searching and fiddling I have something that kinda works, but it is not good enough.

```
titleTextArea.mouseup(function() {
    popup.update(); titleTextArea.focus();
});
```

The problem with the above code is that it also runs when clicking in the textarea. The code I am running causes the textarea to get re-rendered, which should not happen while someone is working in it, as it messes with the focus.

I've tried using jQuery resizable as per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea). For some reason the resize event does not fire. And really I'd prefer not needing to pull in jQuery UI for this.

Is there a way to run code on textbox resize (only on completion of resize is fine) that does not get triggered by a bunch of different actions as well?

(PS: why is there no vanilla event for this?!)

Comment: Did you see this answer on that SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055239/1376624 It uses mouseup too, but might be smoother

Comment: Unfortunately, resize event is consistently supported only for the whole window, or iframe. Learned that the hard way.

Comment: Did you have a look at ResizeObserver API developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver? You can then implement a polyfill to support IE, Edge and Safari like here - https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/GRRLZyJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution can be just adding a check for width/height, not a perfect solution though:

```js
var ta = document.getElementById("text-area");
var width = ta.clientWidth, height = ta.clientHeight
document.getElementById("text-area").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
  if(ta.clientWidth != width || ta.clientHeight != height){
    //do Something
    console.log('resized');
  }
  width = ta.clientWidth;
  height = ta.clientHeight;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text-area" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is so simple. Unsure how I (1) not though of this and (2) missed this solution in the other SO threads. This is the code I ended up with: https://pastebin.com/ZCP6deXG.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
<textarea></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("textarea").resizable({
        resize: function() {
            alert("xxx");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```