# How to handle mouseover event with resize sign in JS?

Tags: javascript

How to handle mouseover event with this textarea resize sign?:
[image]

The easiest solution is to check if the cursor is in a small area in the right-bottom corner. But maybe there's another solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Resize event for textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea)

Since you didn't post what exactly you're trying to do here. Check the link you might get answers

Comment: Bro, I have to handle mouseover but not resize :)

Comment: Mind if i ask what you're trying to do with resize like knowing of user is increasing or decreasing the value or hiding it?

Comment: Pre-resize visual effect

Comment: `function outputsize() {
     width.value = textbox.offsetWidth
     height.value = textbox.offsetHeight
    }
    outputsize()

 <br> new  ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe(textbox)`

Answer (score 0):

you can add the code that you want to execute when the mouseover event occurs. For example, you could change the cursor to a resize cursor to indicate that the element can be resized:

```
const resizeSign = document.querySelector('.resize-sign');

resizeSign.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'resize';
});

resizeSign.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});
```

Comment: Thx, I'm gonna do it. I wish you have a good day :D