# Extjs classic: Textarea with resizable=true cannot be resized

Tags: extjs, textarea, extjs7

I created this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mh2. If you run it, you'll see you cannot resize the textarea even though it has the property `resizable: true`.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['id', 'show'],
            data: [{
                id: 0,
                show: 'Battlestar Galactica'
            }, {
                id: 1,
                show: 'Doctor Who'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                show: 'Farscape'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                show: 'Firefly'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                show: 'Star Trek'
            }, {
                id: 5,
                show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
            width: 400,
            frame: true,
            resizable: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'tagfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
                store: shows,
                displayField: 'show',
                valueField: 'id',
                queryMode: 'local',
                filterPickList: true
            },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    resizable: true,
                    fieldLabel: 'Some label',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    //resizeHandles: 's',
                    //grow: true
                }]
        });
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

To make things more interesting, I took a look at the docs: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html.

I modified the sample to:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
    title      : 'Sample TextArea',
    width      : 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype     : 'textareafield',
        grow      : true,
        name      : 'message',
        fieldLabel: 'Message',
        anchor    : '100%',
        resizable: true,
    }]
});
```

(I added the `resizable: true,` line)
If I click the Run button and I hover the mouse over I get the gray bars.

[image]

On the other form, no matter where I hover the mouse the gray bars don't show up.

But... if I include `grow: true` I am getting some weird mix up in the UI - the gray bars show up eventually, but the position is incorrect.

[image]

How can I get this form to look correct, and still be able to resize the textarea. Resizing the textarea just vertically would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this working in a few steps:

1. Specify a `vbox` layout for the form panel (`align: 'stretch'` is needed to stretch the form fields horizontally when you resize the panel).
2. Wrap the `textareafield` into a `container` with `fit` layout and set `resizable` **on the container and not on the textarea**.
3. You can set further parameters within `resizer` if instead of `true` you use an object which defines an `Ext.resizer.Resizer`, check [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.resizer.Resizer.html) for all config options (`pinned` might be a good idea to show the resize handler always).

As for step 2, I can't tell you for sure why it is not working without the container, but according to the documentation linked abocve, `textarea` resizer is somewhat different, this could be the reason but I can only guess:

> Textarea and img elements will be wrapped with an additional div because these elements do not support child nodes.

One drawback of this solution is that the resize handle appears not only below the `textarea` but the entire container, but this is as far as I could get. I tried `labelAlign: 'top'` on the `textarea` but it adds some space below the label when resizing.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {

        var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['id', 'show'],
            data: [{
                id: 0,
                show: 'Battlestar Galactica'
            }, {
                id: 1,
                show: 'Doctor Who'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                show: 'Farscape'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                show: 'Firefly'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                show: 'Star Trek'
            }, {
                id: 5,
                show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
            width: 400,
            padding: 8,
            frame: true,
            resizable: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'tagfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
                store: shows,
                displayField: 'show',
                valueField: 'id',
                queryMode: 'local',
                filterPickList: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    type: 'fit',
                },
                resizable: {
                    pinned: true,
                    handles: 's',
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    //labelAlign: 'top',
                    grow: true,
                    fieldLabel: 'Some label',
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi - thanks, based on your answer I created this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mhf . It is not needed to set the form layout to vbox. I think your idea with the container did the trick. And I had to add the anchor property otherwise the textarea didn't stretch properly vertically. There are still some strange things. If I resize the form (it is set to resizable:true, let's say I make it wider) and then I resize the textarea, the handle goes off the visible area when I resize the textarea subsequently and go beyond the bottom edge of the form.

Comment: You are welcome. A resizeable field within a resizable panel can be problematic. Although the `resizable` property can configure max height and width but you should update it and correct textarea size depending on the panel size. Unfortunately this property is not bindable. You can use listeners but it will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way (fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3oup)):

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {

        var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['id', 'show'],
            data: [{
                id: 0,
                show: 'Battlestar Galactica'
            }, {
                id: 1,
                show: 'Doctor Who'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                show: 'Farscape'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                show: 'Firefly'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                show: 'Star Trek'
            }, {
                id: 5,
                show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
            //width: 400,
            //height: 800,
            layout: 'fit',
            padding: 8,
            frame: true,
            //resizable: true,

            // layout: {
            //     type: 'vbox',
            //     align: 'stretch',
            // },

            items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'tagfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
                    store: shows,
                    displayField: 'show',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    filterPickList: true
                }, {

                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    //labelAlign: 'top',
                    //grow: true,
                    fieldLabel: 'Some label',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;',
                    fieldStyle: 'resize: vertical;',
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function (resizable) {
                            console.log('afterrender');
                            var formPanel = resizable.up('form');
                            // formPanel.setHeight(formPanel.body.getHeight() + formPanel.getFrameHeight());
                            console.log(formPanel.findParentByType('panel'));
                            function outputsize() {
                                //console.log(resizable.getHeight());
                                formPanel.findParentByType('panel').updateLayout();
                            }

                            console.log(resizable);
                            new ResizeObserver(outputsize).observe(resizable.getEl().dom);
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'tagfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Select a Show',
                    store: shows,
                    displayField: 'show',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    filterPickList: true
                }]
            }],

        });
    }
});
```

Some points:

- I made the textarea resizable vertically using the `resizable: vertical;` style
- I placed the form in another panel that has the `layout: 'fit'`, because I wanted this panel to expand to fit the content of the form panel
- I added a resize listener for the textarea using the info found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312642/832783. The listener simply updates the layout of the parent panel which in turn resizes it to embrace the entire content of the form panel.